# for_each value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-route53

i am trying to create route 53 using module concept. but getting below error.
"The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created."
for_each = var.create-route53 ? local.recordsets : tomap({})

**local.recordsets will be known only after apply**
var.create-route53 is true

can someone guide me on this ?

actual code:

```
module "route53" {
...
...
  records = [
    {
      name    = "test-name"
      type    = "A"
      ttl     = 300
      records = [for instance in module.ec2: instance.ec2-IP      
      ]
    },
  ]
  vpc_id = "${module.vpc.vpc_id}"
} 

Inside modules folder below code will be there in route53 folder:

locals {
  records = try(jsondecode(var.records), var.records)
   recordsets = {
    for rs in local.records :
    join(" ", compact(["${rs.name} ${rs.type}", lookup(rs, "set_identifier", "")])) => merge(rs, {
      records = jsonencode(try(rs.records, null))
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "this" {
  for_each = var.create-route53 ? local.recordsets : tomap({})
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.private.zone_id
  name                             = each.value.name != "" ? "${each.value.name}" : "test"
  type                             = each.value.type
  ttl                              = lookup(each.value, "ttl", null)
  records                          = jsondecode(each.value.records)
  set_identifier                   = lookup(each.value, "set_identifier", null)
  health_check_id                  = lookup(each.value, "health_check_id", null)
  multivalue_answer_routing_policy = lookup(each.value, "multivalue_answer_routing_policy", null)
  allow_overwrite                  = lookup(each.value, "allow_overwrite", false)
}
```

Comment: What do you pass in as `var.records`?

Comment: Below record sent from parent module in var.records 
```
  records = [
    {
      name    = "test-name"
      type    = "A"
      ttl     = 300
      records = [for instance in module.ec2: instance.ec2-IP      
      ]
    },
  ]
```

Comment: That does not work since the module.ec2 is probably only available after apply, particularly the ips of the created instances. You may be able to work around that by splitting the input into the actual dynamic input containing the IP and other things AND the other input being primarily the names of the instances or just a number of instances. That way terraform knows how many records to create but the actual contents of the records can only be determined during apply.

Comment: This concept is taken from terraform modules page , thought it should be working..
actual code :
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-route53/blob/master/modules/records/main.tf
example for module :
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/route53/aws/latest

Comment: Can you provide an example for spitting like you mentioned in your example?

Comment: @sam were you able to solve this issue? if yes could you please share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the usage of `jsondecode(var.records)` in the module. Because `var.records` contains calculated attributes, the result of the `jsondecode` is also marked as calculated, and Terraform throws the error.

I suspect Terraform doesn't execute the jsondecode function at plan time iff its operand contains calculated attributes (it does get executed at plan time when it doens't contain any calculated attributes), but I'm not entirely sure. That would explain why it doesn't figure out that the keys in the `local.recordset` are in fact known at plan time.

In the [example module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-route53/blob/master/modules/records/main.tf) that is linked to in the comments of the question, it seems they try to solve this by explicitly accepting json-encoded input (which is unlikely to contain calculated attributes, otherwise you could just as well pass it to the module as a normal HCL map/object via `var.records`; I suspect these records contain information from outside of the current state) as a separate input variable.

So as a quick fix: don't apply the `jsondecode` function on the `records` input variable, if those records are constructed by information that is calculated in the state.